# Python - search spreadsheet for cell containing datetime string

Tags: python, excel, pandas, string, datetime

I'm a Python newbie and this is my first SO post. I'm trying to use python to extract a datestamp from a cell in a spreadsheet. I tried the following:

```
    df = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=0)
    df_columns = dict(zip(df.columns,range(len(df.columns))))
    df_start = df.rename(columns=df_columns)
    for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            if isinstance(df.iloc[i,j],str) and ':' in df.loc[i,j]:
                datestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(df.iloc[i,j], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
                break
```

I'm getting an error message "Error at 0".

Dataframe looks something like this:

|  0  |   1 |   2 |...| 10  |             11          |  12 |

|---- | ----| --- |...|---- | ------------------------| --- |

| NaN | NaN | NaN |...| NaN | 2022-09-16 16:47:21.852 | NaN |

| NaN | NaN | NaN |...| NaN | 2022-09-16 16:47:21.852 | NaN |

| NaN | NaN | NaN |...| NaN |      NaN                | NaN |

| NaN |   NaN     |      NaN     |...| NaN |      NaN   | NaN |

| NaN |ClientName |Client Number |...|Core  | Core Description  | Status |

| NaN |AB09403880 |9403880|...|NaN  | NaN | Active |

| NaN |AB09403881 |9403881|...|NaN  | NaN | Active |

| NaN |AB09403882 |9403883|...|NaN  | NaN | Active |

---

EDIT: I want to extract the datestamp in this spreadsheet to add as a column to a different dataframe which will eventually be written to CSV file. I should also add that the column where the date stamp is located is not necessarily going to be in column 11 (row 1 & 2) in the spreadsheet hence my attempt to loop through the cells. Hope that makes sense.

---

EDIT 2: Updated additional rows of dataframe

Expected Output:

| Datestamp|ClientName |Client Number |...|Core  | Core Description  | Status |

| 2022-09-16 |AB09403880 |9403880|...|NaN  | NaN | Active |

| 2022-09-16 |AB09403881 |9403881|...|NaN  | NaN | Active |

| 2022-09-16 |AB09403882 |9403883|...|NaN  | NaN | Active |

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your Excel files has only timestamps values distributed in multiple rows/cols (see example/dataframe below) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("myinnernerd.xlsx")

print(df)

                         0    1    2    3                        4                        5    6    7    8    9                        10                       11                       12
0                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN  2022-09-16 16:47:21.852                      NaN
1                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN  2022-09-16 16:47:21.852                      NaN
2                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN  2022-09-16 16:47:21.852  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN                      NaN
3                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN                      NaN
4   2022-09-16 16:47:21.852  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2022-09-16 16:47:21.852                      NaN                      NaN
5                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN                      NaN
6                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN                      NaN
7                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2022-09-16 16:47:21.852  2022-09-16 16:47:21.852  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN                      NaN
8                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2022-09-16 16:47:21.852                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN                      NaN
9                       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN                      NaN
10                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                      NaN                      NaN  2022-09-16 16:47:21.852
```

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.stack`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to intersect all the columns then [**`pandas.DataFrame.explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to explode the rows with eventually multiple timestamps :

```
f = lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x
df['datestamp'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(f)
df = df.pop('datestamp').dropna().explode().to_frame()
```

After that, convert the column `datestamp` to a datetime object by using [**`pandas.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) then floor it by seconds `'S'`.

```
df['datestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datestamp']).dt.floor('S')

print(df)

             datestamp
0  2022-09-16 16:47:21
1  2022-09-16 16:47:21
2  2022-09-16 16:47:21
4  2022-09-16 16:47:21
4  2022-09-16 16:47:21
7  2022-09-16 16:47:21
7  2022-09-16 16:47:21
8  2022-09-16 16:47:21
10 2022-09-16 16:47:21

print(df.dtypes)
datestamp    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @abokey. I edited my original post with additional info: my intentions and datestamp location may vary (not necessarily in column 11/row1&2).

Comment: Is it possible to have two timestamps in the same row ? Does your excel file has other values than timestamps ? If so, you need to share a good sample of your dataset and not only two rows. Anyways, I made an update to my answer, check it out !

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and no dice. I got this error 'Error at Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values'. I tried adding more rows of data but it was all jumbled up and I was afraid it would cause more confusion (new poster limitations). There are only 2 cells in top right corner of my sheet with datestamp (parsed to show date and time). The rest of my report consists of data in columns and rows. I want to find the datestamp and add a column to the rest of  the data and export to csv. My problem is locating those 2 cells in top right corner. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Again "top right corner" on this one example is Column 11 / Rows 1&2 but can be Column 4 / Rows 3&4 on another sheet.

Comment: It would be much simpler if you share a sample of your dataset rather than 2 single rows.

Comment: sorry, this is my first post and I'm still figuring out what I can post (SO won't let me post images until I have enough 'reputations').

Comment: No worries, maybe you can share a part of your dataset in Google docs (as .xlsx) ?

Comment: I manually added some rows and an expected output. Please take a look and see if makes sense. If not, I will try the Google docs route. Thanks so much for your help and quick responses. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but only because there are no other datestamps in the excel file:

```
def rep_date(df):
    x = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64])
    y = x.iloc[1].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').to_string(index=False)
    return y
```